# my app is crashing when i am passing data from recycler adapter to activity using intents i want to pass restaurant id

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

holder.llContent.setOnClickListener {
println(holder.txtRestaurantName.tag.toString())

```
        val intent=Intent(context,RestaurantMenuActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("restaurantId",holder.txtRestaurantName.tag.toString())
        intent.putExtra("restaurantName",holder.txtRestaurantName.text.toString())
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: You don't really have a whole lot of code here, but I suggest using an interface to your activity rather than startActivity()

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a click listener function in your adapter, it will be callable from your activity.

First add this to your adapter class:

```
private var onItemClickListener: ((YourDataModel) -> Unit)? = null

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: ((YourDataModel) -> Unit)) {
    onItemClickListener = listener
}
```

Then in your adapter, for the `view` which you want to set the click listener, add this line:

```
view.setOnClickListener {
    onItemClickListener?.let { it(dataModel) }
}
```

> Note: `dataModel` is considered a request response Kotlin object, you can pass any other parameter (another normal function :)), Like a restaurant ID or anything.

Now you can use it in your activity like this:

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener {
    // What you want to do
}
```